# How do I get rid of this annoying overlay in the android Studio UI (see pic in description)

Tags: android-studio

Sometimes this yellow overlay will start showing in Android Studio.

[image: Annoying Overlay]

It doesn't happen all of the time but once it's there it will not go away until I restart AS. It wants to help me navigate to the last spot I was at in the code but a) I can already do that with ALT + Arow keys and b) it hides the code I'm actually trying to read so it's not only useful it's actively harmful. I can't find a setting anywhere that will let me get rid of it.

Does anyone know?